# Variable different on php echo and javascript alert

Tags: php, javascript

I have a dynamic multilanguage website. 
My php echos the current language right, but javascript doesn't even if loading after body.

My php:

```
<?php echo $language ?>
```

This gives me english, portuguese, german or french accordingly to the one is being used.

when i try with javascript this way:

```
    <script type="text/javascript">
    function language() {
        var ci = {
            language : "<?php echo $language; ?>"
        };
        if(ci.language = 'portuguese') {
            alert(ci.language);
            return false;
            fb_language = "pt_PT";
        } else if (ci.language = 'english') {
            alert(ci.language);
            return false;
            fb_language = "en_US";
        } else if (ci.language = 'german') {
            alert(ci.language);
            return false;
            fb_language = "de_DE";
        } else if (ci.language = 'french') {
            alert(ci.language);
            return false;
            fb_language = "fr_FR";
        } else {
            fb_language = "en_US";
        }
    };
    </script>

<body onload="language();">
```

It always gives me portuguese in javascript, can't make it alert the right language, but in php it gives me the right language im using.

Comment: You are assigning, not comparing. Two equals signs.

Comment: 1. = != == && == != === , 2. http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_switch.asp

Comment: Thank you all for the quick answer. :D

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This:

```
if(ci.language = 'portuguese') {
```

Should be:

```
if(ci.language === 'portuguese') {
```

And so on in the other `if` statements.

Comment: Thank you very much, so stupid question. This can be closed.

Comment: You're welcome, my friend. Next time consider to post it on [Code Review](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/).

Answer (score 1):

Use as:
`ci.language == 'portuguese'` instead of `ci.language = 'portuguese'`